# How can I remove columns of pandas dataframe conditional on last row values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

Given a data-frame like:

```
             A  B  C
2019-11-02  120 25 11
2019-11-03  119 28 15
2019-11-04  115 23 18
2019-11-05  119 30 20
2019-11-06  121 32 25
2019-11-07  117 24 30
```

I would like to remove the columns in which the value of the last row is less than (<) a constant X,  say X = 25. In this example It would remove the column B only and the output would be:

```
             A  C
2019-11-02  120 11
2019-11-03  119 15
2019-11-04  115 18
2019-11-05  119 20
2019-11-06  121 25
2019-11-07  117 30
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1:

Use `iloc`, `lt`, and `drop`:

We select the last row with `iloc[-1]`, then check which column is `less than (lt)` `25` and pass that column to `DataFrame.drop`

```
df = df.drop(columns = df.columns[df.iloc[-1].lt(25)])
```

#### Method 2:

Using `tail`, `iloc`, `gt` and `all`:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.tail(1).gt(25).all()]
```

```
              A   C
2019-11-02  120  11
2019-11-03  119  15
2019-11-04  115  18
2019-11-05  119  20
2019-11-06  121  25
2019-11-07  117  30
```

---

**Step by step method 1**:

```
# select last row

df.iloc[-1]

A    117
B     24
C     30
Name: 2019-11-07, dtype: int64
```

```
# check which columns have value < 25:

df.iloc[-1].lt(25)

A    False
B     True
C    False
Name: 2019-11-07, dtype: bool
```

```
# select those column(s) with boolean indexing:

df.columns[df.iloc[-1].lt(25)]

Index(['B'], dtype='object')
```

```
# finally pass it DataFrame.drop

df.drop(columns = df.columns[df.iloc[-1].lt(25)])

              A   C
2019-11-02  120  11
2019-11-03  119  15
2019-11-04  115  18
2019-11-05  119  20
2019-11-06  121  25
2019-11-07  117  30
```

Comment: In case you want to modify the dataframe `df` then you can include the flag `inplace` as `True`. Take a look on the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: I am aware, it just to showcase as example. Btw `inplace=True` is discouraged and will be removed in future version of pandas

Comment: Yup, just sharing it as a comment in case anybody wants to know it. ;-)